# How should I configure Theano to allow Keras handle an ANN using the GPU (& her CUDA cores) instead of the CPU?

Tags: machine-learning, cygwin, anaconda, theano, keras

Trying to change `theano.config.device` in '`gpu`' instead of '`cpu`', in **Python 3.5** under **Anaconda3** (mounted on a *Windows 10 Workstation*).

I get as response the message :

```
 "Can't change the value of this config parameter after initialization!".
```

On the other hand, if I run '`export THEANO_FLAGS = device = gpu`' from bash **Cygwin64**, going back in **Anaconda**, the value remains fixed as '`cpu`'.

**Attention:** Somewhere I read "`Edit or create the file ~/.theanorc`". Ok, would you try doing it under Windows?

Answer (score 0):

My installation steps:

1. install Anaconda Python
2. in command prompt:

```
conda install git libpython mingw

pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git

pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git
```

3. in command prompt:

```
python

import keras
```

At the first run you will see an error that you don't have Tensorflow backend.

Win+R to open the Run dialog

enter `%HOMEPATH%`

go in `.keras` folder and edit `keras.json` in notepad: replace 'tensorflow' with 'theano'

4. close and open command prompt again:

```
python

import keras
```

Now it should work.

**Additional steps for GPU support:**

5. install Visual Studio 2015 (see step 1 in [Phil Ferriere's guide](https://github.com/philferriere/dlwin))
6. install CUDA 8.0
7. extract cuDNN 5.1 files in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0`
8. configure Theano:

Win+R to open the Run dialog

enter `%HOMEPATH%`

create `.theanorc.txt` with config in it:

```
[global]

floatX = float32

device = gpu0

mode = FAST_RUN
```

Comment: Well, Alexey, theano.config 'floatX' and 'mode' are Ok, now, but the command 'cnmem' caused a lot of error messages, like these: "nvcc fatal: cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH", or "ERROR (theano sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu", and finally "WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu0 is not available (error: cuda unavailable)"...

Comment: @FrancescoMaggiore See this [guide](https://github.com/philferriere/dlwin). You need to do step 1 (install Visual Studio 2015 or add it to PATH if you have it installed) and step 8 (download cuDNN and copy it in CUDA directory). Visual Studio installation will fix the errors with compilation like "cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH". cuDNN will accelerate your calculations. If you will see error at the import of Keras/Theano that you have not enough memory on GPU, try to delete 'cnmem=0.8' from config. In normal situation this reserves 80% of your GPU's memory and accelerates calculations.

Comment: Following all the instructions till the 4th point, I thought I'm managing to get on top of this issue. Unfortunately happened this: previously I had used the Cygwin bash, but since it was clear that going along it was better to uninstall what I had previously installed, I removed Cygwin, too. After I installed the January 2017 version of MinGW-w64, I read taht Philferriere suggests to do a check from the command prompt, but it seems a bash, which at this point I have no longer available. Even MinGW, infact, open a Windows command prompt ... What do you recommend I do?

Comment: @FrancescoMaggiore In command prompt: `conda install libpython mingw`.

Comment: I want first of all to thank you for the patience you are demonstrating, because maybe you will not believe, but I also asked some universities here in Italy, but no one seems to use Keras and Theano under Windows, but only in the Unix environment, and without your suggestions I would be unable to move forward...

Comment: Ok, perhaps I haven't explained so well what is happened: I have correctly installed MinGW, but in the article that you have recommended to me, after the installation the author suggests to check it by opening a "command prompt" which is actually a bash, because the prompt is "$". After uninstalling Cygwin, I do not have any program to open a window like this: what I should do?

Comment: @FrancescoMaggiore We can try a remote connection to your computer via [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com) in Saturday or Sunday. Let me know time that is convenient for you. I am in the Moscow timezone (your local time + 2 hours). My email: `alexey.golyshev@live.com`